# MySQL covering index optimization?

Tags: mysql, indexing, covering-index

I have a table with the following structure below:

```
Id (Int), Telephone_Number (Int), Name (VARCHAR), Address (VARCHAR)
```

I wish to create a covering index for this SELECT query:

```
SELECT Id FROM mytable WHERE Telephone_Number = '55442233';
```

I understand covering indexes remove the amount of Disk I/O as the indexes are stored in the memory cache, therefore increasing performance.

For my SELECT query, am I right in saying making Id an index will not remove the need for Disk I/O due to the WHERE clause needing access to the Telephone_Number value?

If so, would a composite index of `(Id, Telephone_Number)` work as a covering index? Or do covering index have to be single column's?

Comment: I think you should also check what is an `Index` because they increase performance because they created a b-tree making search faster. Doesnt have anything to do with memory cache.

Comment: The columns in your index need to be reversed. Apperently, you are lacking quite some basics about indexing. You might want to read my (free online) indexing book: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/table-of-contents — Covering indexes are explained in chapter 5 in the section "index only scan".

Comment: You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), and the video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU

Comment: Index blocks are _cached_ in RAM, as are data blocks.  They are not _stored_ in RAM.  The covering index you need is in the opposite order:  `INDEX(telephone_number, id)`.  [_Cookbook_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/)